# Why is a standard ImageButton too small in Android?

Tags: android-layout, android-button, android-imagebutton

For most of the UI of an app, I want it as conventional as possible. An ImageButton is devised by following [the official recommendation](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/button)

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonCloseAd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:contentDescription="@string/close"
    android:src="@drawable/baseline_cancel_24" />
```

The icon baseline_cancel_24 is created by using all default settings of the vector assets:
[image]

Android Studio gives the error "This item's height is 32dp. Consider making the height of this touch target 48dp or larger. " for the button though the app can be built with this error:
[image]

Could anyone shed some light on this and offer the conventional way to make an ImageButton comply with the guideline?

In case you wonder and for your convenience, here is [the official sample code for ImageButton](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/button):

```
  <ImageButton
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:contentDescription="A tiny Android icon"
      android:src="@drawable/baseline_android_24"
      app:tint="#ff0000" />
```

Comment: Make the button width 48dp or add some padding.